# Can't install pandoc in OS X 10.7.5 using Homebrew

Tags: homebrew, osx-lion, pandoc

I just installed Homebrew on Lion 10.7.5 (it did complain that it is not supported, so I am aware that this may be the reason). I tried to install pandoc, and apparently cryptonite is causing problems.

```
~ $ brew install pandoc
Warning: You are using macOS 10.7.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.
==> Using the sandbox
==> Downloading https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-1.18/pandoc-1.18.tar.
Already downloaded: /Users/username/Library/Caches/Homebrew/pandoc-1.18.tar.gz
==> cabal sandbox init
==> cabal update
==> cabal install --jobs=4 --max-backjumps=100000 --only-dependencies --constrai
Last 15 lines from /Users/username/Library/Logs/Homebrew/pandoc/03.cabal:
Installed pandoc-types-1.17.0.4
Downloading texmath-0.8.6.7...
Configuring texmath-0.8.6.7...
Building texmath-0.8.6.7...
Installed texmath-0.8.6.7
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
connection-0.2.6 depends on cryptonite-0.20 which failed to install.
cryptonite-0.20 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
http-client-tls-0.3.3 depends on cryptonite-0.20 which failed to install.
tls-1.3.8 depends on cryptonite-0.20 which failed to install.
x509-1.6.4 depends on cryptonite-0.20 which failed to install.
x509-store-1.6.2 depends on cryptonite-0.20 which failed to install.
x509-system-1.6.4 depends on cryptonite-0.20 which failed to install.
x509-validation-1.6.5 depends on cryptonite-0.20 which failed to install.

READ THIS: https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting
If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/brew):
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues

Warning: You are using macOS 10.7.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.
```

I hope I can install pandoc on 10.7.5. This is a MBP early 2011 with 4 GB RAM. Newer versions run very slowly, so I'd prefer not to upgrade from Lion, unless I have to.

UPDATE: I ended up upgrading to Mavericks. Everything worked just fine (some hiccups, nothing major). Homebrew installed fine, then pandoc was installed with Homebrew and now everything is humming.

Comment: get a `.dmg` from http://pandoc.org/installing.html (not sure which pandoc version still supports lion, you might have to go for an older one...)

Comment: Yup, the most recent version, 1.18, does not support Lion. Maybe that's why it cannot be installed using Homebrew, because it cannot be installed at all. I need to find out which version does support Lion.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by https://discourse.brew.sh/t/how-to-install-old-version-of-a-formula, I found a workaround.

As Homebrew doesn't offer Pandoc `< 2.0` anymore, we need to sneak it into the current formula like so:

- `$ cd "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)"`
- In `Formula/pandoc.rb`, replace the contents of `url` with `https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-1.19.2.4/pandoc-1.19.2.4.tar.gz` and the contents of `sha256` with `bbe08c1f7fcfea98b899f9956c04159d493a26f65d3350aa6579aa5b93203556`

Now you can install Pandoc: `$ brew install pandoc`.